# Parallel job fails at Lookup stage when reaching 4GB

Tags: parallel-processing, datastage

There is parallel job that consists of one data set, one sequential file and a lookup stage that joins them.

The sequential file contains 15,811 rows. It is imported just fine (and I can see this in the log).

The problem is with the lookup stage - it throws the following error:

```
LOOKUP,0: Could not map table file "/var/opt/ascential/adm/DataSet1/lookuptable.20140330.spzjazc (size 4191844864 bytes)": Not enough space
Error finalizing / saving table /tmp/dynLUT18950c3139ce
```

As I read on IBM website and other forums a possible solution could be to increase the number of nodes. So I changed my APT file from 1 node to 6 nodes:

```
{
        node "node1"
        {
                fastname "xxx"
                pools ""
                resource disk "/var/opt/ascential/adm/DataSet1" {pools ""}
                resource scratchdisk "/var/opt/ascential/adm/Scratch1" {pools ""}
        }
        node "node2"
        {
                fastname "xxx"
                pools ""
                resource disk "/var/opt/ascential/adm/DataSet2" {pools ""}
                resource scratchdisk "/var/opt/ascential/adm/Scratch2" {pools ""}
        }
        node "node3"
        {
                fastname "xxx"
                pools ""
                resource disk "/var/opt/ascential/adm/DataSet3" {pools ""}
                resource scratchdisk "/var/opt/ascential/adm/Scratch3" {pools ""}
        }
        node "node4"
        {
                fastname "xxx"
                pools ""
                resource disk "/var/opt/ascential/adm/DataSet4" {pools ""}
                resource scratchdisk "/var/opt/ascential/adm/Scratch4" {pools ""}
        }
        node "node5"
        {
                fastname "xxx"
                pools ""
                resource disk "/var/opt/ascential/adm/DataSet5" {pools ""}
                resource scratchdisk "/var/opt/ascential/adm/Scratch5" {pools ""}
        }
        node "node6"
        {
                fastname "xxx"
                pools ""
                resource disk "/var/opt/ascential/adm/DataSet6" {pools ""}
                resource scratchdisk "/var/opt/ascential/adm/Scratch6" {pools ""}
        }
}
```

Still, I get the same error and I noticed that the job writes only to the first DataSet folder (there is a file called /var/opt/ascential/adm/DataSet1/lookuptable.20140330.spzjazc that grows in size until it reaches ~4GB then the job fails and the file is removed).

1. I assume the job is not actually running on multiple nodes since there is only 1 file. Is this correct? How can I force it to run on all 6 nodes so that I can overcome the 4 GB limitation?
2. Are there any other workarounds for this?

Comment: Although I was not able to overcome the 4GB limitation I managed to fix the issue by changing the size of one of the input columns from VARCHAR(762) to VARCHAR(20). This seemed to have a big impact in terms of file size of the DataSet files and in terms of job duration (the job duration decreased from 15 minutes to 2 minutes). Also, it seems that using a Join instead of Lookup stage could do the trick, as well (I tested it on a smaller volume of data and it worked fine). More details: http://tinyurl.com/omzm8ux

Answer (score 1):

The lookup stage loads all the data in the memory.
So that's perfectly normal what you have here.
Maybe you can change it to merge stage or join stage.

Answer (score 0):

Random is correct.

If you're using Datastage PX to model a left join and the right-side table's data volume is large or unpredictable, then you need to use a join stage instead of lookup stage.

Merge stage is a specialized/optimized join, which most people don't need and shouldn't use.

Answer (score 0):

The lookup stage should be used to process little ammount of data:
[Join vs Lookup](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_8.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.dev.doc/topics/c_deeref_Join_Versus_Lookup.html)

The sequential file is readed in sequential mode (using only one node), could you add a job that converts the sequential into a dataset file? The dataset files use parallel mode (many nodes).

In otherwise, you can use the join stage, having in count that setting the left link to the file with most data, due to left link assigns it more resources than the rigth link.